# A bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Z}^4$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

> Prove that $\mathbb{N}$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{Z}^4$.

I was thinking of construct a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Z}^4$, and a way which I think can be used is combining a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and a bijection from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}^2$. And I stuck here.

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Which of these two bijections do you have trouble with? You could alternatively build something with  $\Bbb N\to \Bbb N^2$ and $\Bbb N\to\Bbb Z$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Have a look at *Cantor's pairing function*.

The basic idea is that, by forming an array, you can wind your way around and get a bijection between the cross product of a countable set with itself and $\Bbb N$ (or $\Bbb Z$).  The point is that it's countable.